# Proving a transformation satisfies T(cv) = cT(v) but not T(v + w) = T(v) + T(w)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a doubt in the following question.

Suppose $T(\vec v) = \vec v$, except that $T(0, v_2) = (0, 0)$. Show that this transformation
satisfies $T(cv) = cT(v)$ but not $T(v + w) = T(v) + T(w)$.

I don't understand T(0, v2) = (0, 0), any help with this question appreciated.

Comment: Not clear ! what is $v_2$ ? What is $T$ ?

Comment: Thats what my question is :-( I think it could be the second component of vector v which is composed of v1, v2 ?

Comment: T is transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a transformation $T : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ defined as follows: for any vector $\vec v = (v_1,v_2)$,
$$
T(\vec v) = 
\begin{cases}
\vec v & v_1 \neq 0\\
(0,0) & v_1 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Hopefully, the question is a bit clearer now.

Note that if the first component of $\vec v$ is non-zero, then the same will be true for $c \vec v$, when $c \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it is clear now.